# Eclipse on mac with google app engine plug in

Tags: eclipse, macos, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm new to Eclipse and App engine, following google getting started tutorial here i've installed eclipse kepler (4.3) and the according google app engine sdk (https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3)

[image]
[image]

when trying to create a new web application project i get the error: failed to initialized app engine

I've read relevant post and could not find something that worked for me.

Comment: I got the same error with AppEngine java-sdk 1.8.5, tried to manually configure it, but to no avail

Comment: @DileepaJayakody maybe upgrade the question and someone will have the motivation to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the same problem but no way to solve. Via plugin or manually installed it returns same error:  Failed to initialized App Engine SDK!
Have you tried with Java SDK 1.7?

The solution is: You have to downgrade to appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4.

Comment: Yep, that works! You can download appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4 from here : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/downloads/detail?name=appengine-java-sdk-1.8.4.zip even it says the package is deprecated, just continue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Upgraded to the Java SDK 1.7 and the error message went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upgrading to JDK7 was not enough for me. I had to switch from Eclipse Kepler 32bits to a 64bits version. Now it works with GAE SDK 1.8.6.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK7 requirement is actually mentioned in the appengine page [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_Introduction) :

> Warning: The App Engine SDK no longer supports Java 6. Applications that use Java 6 need to be migrated to Java 7. Existing applications that use the Java 6 runtime are still supported, but this support will be removed in a future release.